# Displaying a Paged Grid of Data in ASP.NET MVC error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

i'm trying to make a paged grid of data and using the portion of Code

```
public ActionResult Paged(int page , int pageSize)
{
   var model = new UserGridModel()
   {
      CurrentPageIndex = page,
      PageSize = pageSize
   };

   // Determine the total number of users being paged through (needed to compute PageCount)
   model.TotalRecordCount = this.DataContext.users.Count();

   // Get the current page of users
   //model.CurrentPageIndex = this.DataContext.users.Skip((model.CurrentPageIndex - 1) * model.PageSize).Take(model.PageSize);
   model.users = this.DataContext.users
                     .Skip((model.CurrentPageIndex - 1) * model.PageSize)
                     .Take(model.PageSize);

   return View(model);
}
```

The Problem is

> Error 2   'New.Models.UserGridModel' does not contain a definition for
>   'users' and no extension method 'users' accepting a first argument of
>   type

any idea to solve it

Comment: I think you're going to need to add more info. I'm not seeing any correlation between the error and the code snippet.